# Intellitrace is not available for native or mixed-mode debugging

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010, intellitrace

I just opened an old C project in Visual Studio 2010 and tried to understand Intellitrace. But I get this error message

Intellitrace is not available for native or mixed-mode debugging

I searched a bit on SO and found similar but not yet resolved questions. Do you know what could be the problem? Thanks

Comment: Hmya, the emphasis here is on the word "managed".  Once you can manage code execution, there's a wholelotta goodies that become available.  Verification being the bigger one btw.  The point of C is quite the opposite, run as fast as you can and don't waste time leaving breadcrumbs that would be helpful when it blows up.  Like a stack trace that is walkable at runtime.

Comment: can somehow a C code / VS project forced to be managed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just as with Visual Studio 2010, Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate also does not provide Intellitrace for native apps.

In Visual Studio 2012, Intellitrace is available for:

- Visual Basic and Visual C# apps that use the .NET Framework 2.0, 3.0,
  3.5, 4.0, or 4.5.
- F# apps
- Windows Store apps supported for events only

It is not available for:

- C++, script, or other languages
- Silverlight, Xbox, or Windows Mobile apps

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd264915.aspx for more info.

Answer (score 2):

The Intellitrace technology is currently only available on managed projects.  Mixed-mode by definition contains native code therefore it is disabled.

Comment: holy crap! And nothing can be done to my project so it can use this amazing feature?

Comment: Not currently.  There have been many request for this feature though.

Comment: oh man :( stupid microsoft people, I can not imagine what hidden interests are there ...

Comment: by the way, I know that gdb implements reverse debugging, but is it here some IDE (Eclipse, Xcode, etc) for C++ that can graphically work with something similar?

Comment: I am also familiar with that functionality within `gdb` but I am not aware of a UI that exposes it.  I would check `DDD` but I could not find a definitive answer from their site, but its last release was prior to the inclusion of that technology in `gdb`.

Comment: VMWare has some nice tools that work on native code. Check out www.replaydebugging.com

Answer (score 0):

Intellitrace only works for managed debugging (eg. C# or vb).