# Restore IntelliTrace Window in Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate

Tags: intellitrace

I closed by mistake IntellyTrace Window. Before i did it I saw IntellyTrace Window and stack trace inside by default while I debug. But recently I close this windows someway and stil can't restore it.

I read this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd572114.aspx but nothing works. I just want to see again IntelliTrace Windows and nowhere I can find the working solution.

Does anyone faced with it? Or How to restore all intelliTrace properies?
Seems like there is the same problem, maybe there it describes better:
https://twitter.com/KevinDockx/statuses/253502498806059009

thanks

Answer (score 3):

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jankrivanek/archive/2013/02/05/why-are-intellitrace-windows-and-menus-missing.aspx

This Microsoft blog post explains how some project debugging options will hide these menu items.

Comment: I had the same issue in VS 2013

Comment: I suspect my issue is similar, but I can't find the right set of options that is causing it.  This is a C#, ASP.NET MVC5 project type, and the Debug pane is not present in the project properties.  I have made sure to attach to only managed debugging.  Still won't show up.

Answer (score 1):

Go to `Debug -> Intellitrace` and select either `Intellitrace Calls` or `Intellitrace Events`. You also have to make sure you're on a breakpoint or else those options won't be shown.

Hope this helps.

Comment: BINGO!  The Intellitrace debug windows just wouldn't open up unless I was sitting at a breakpoint.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I found this post: [Intellitrace is not available for native or mixed-mode debugging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3799854/intellitrace-is-not-available-for-native-or-mixed-mode-debugging?rq=1). Seems like someway it set debugger type is "mixed" in project properties.
I back it to "managed" and I see IntelliTrace Window.